# Which is the most accurate temperature sensor in the market?

Tags: sensor, temperature

I have been working on a project requiring very accurate and precise measurements of temperature, of the order of +-0.1 degrees Celcius (or the closest to this), I have been using a LM-35 and as expected, the results weren't great, specially horrible for my application. 
Can anyone suggest me any good temperature sensor, I was thinking about the Bosch BME-280, but later learnt it is primarily for humidity and pressure measurements and might not be accurate enough for my application.
I have also tried DHT11/22 series, but it was worthless too.
I have not tried ds18b20 yet, is it recommended?

Edit 1: The measurement is to be made in the range of 36.5-37.5 degrees Celsius, accuracy of the order of +-0.1 degrees Celcius is desired.
Edit 2: I know basic programming with Arduino, but have never calibrated a sensor before.

Comment: What's preventing you from searching like the rest of us?

Comment: @pipe I have mentioned all the sensors I have tried, might not have been able to try all of them, and to my limited electronics background, might not have stumbled upon the right options. Somenone with hands-on experience in working with them should be able to help much better than a Google search!

Comment: Percent of what? At what temperature and environment? More info needed.

Comment: Research Pt100 sensors

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I have made the necessary edits.

Comment: You don't search on google, you search on any component distributor and sort by tolerance.

Comment: @pipe Thanks for the advice, will keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Also how fast do you need it to respond?  You've asked if things work with Arduino or RPi3, so you should add that to the question.  If you have a microcontroller present and programming is an option for you, you may be able to calibrate it.

Comment: @KH I have now added that to the question. The sensor should be able to respond in time steps of 2 secs.

Comment: @KH It doesn't really matter. Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic anyway.

Comment: pt100 sensor in wheatstone bridge with tempco stable 100 ohm resistor is the way to go.

Comment: Drift, noise, and absolute accuracy are all different things. I have used a $0.50 thermistor that easily meets your specs, but it has noise and needs repeated measurements. It also needed manual calibration. So I'd be interested to know more about the application, for example to know whether noise is allowed (if it becomes dead accurate when averaged over a thousand samples).

Comment: @Pipe I'm seeing a bit of an XY question here, especially if he's using a microcontroller.  I don't think he even needs the most accurate sensor for .1C, just any reasonably accurate sensor, well used.  Not that more accuracy is bad.

Comment: @piojo The application is a chamber with controlled temperature, the temperature range maintenance being the most important design factor.

Comment: @KH Can you please explain me how that can be done? I am just a beginner in electronics (as already mentioned), my apologies if the answer is trivial.

Comment: I think the other recent comments are right. You don't need a super accurate temperature sensor, as long as the readings next month are the same as the readings today (not high drift). As long as the sensor isn't actually inconsistent, I'd take a step back and post a new question about exactly what is not working in your circuit and/or controller.

Comment: @Kv07 I assume you mean how do you calibrate a sensor.  In order to do so, you need a second device that can measure accurately, even if analog, and compare the input of the sensor to known temperatures.  If you're programming on an arduino, this sort of thing can become easy, especially if you have access to the raw sensor input.  You'll need an analog input or a ADC.

Comment: @KH22 Thanks for your help, I will try searching the internet and calibrate my LM35 to see what comes out. Also, if we can calibrate any sensor, why do we have more accurate sensors in the first place? Is it because they circumvent the calibration by the user and are directly plug and play?

Answer (score 1):

I depends on how much you want to spend. For example PT100 RTD sensor is very accurate if you hook it on a high end DAQ board.

http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/hardware-reference-design/circuits-from-the-lab/CN0381.html#rd-overview

Comment: Will it work with an Arduino or RP3?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Look for details.

Answer (score -2):

Before this gets closed. [Sensirion](https://www.sensirion.com/) produces all kinds of environment sensors. The [STS3X](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/0_Datasheets/Temperature/Sensirion_Temperature_Sensors_STS3x_Datasheet.pdf) series might be what you're looking for (no, I don't have any connections to Sensirion, just used their sensors before)